# Possible to create email address without name information? ie: '@example.com'

Tags: email

I'm curious as to whether it would be possible to create an email address without the name information. So, `@example.com` rather than `name@example.com`.

Comment: No. However, you can often create a catch-all address, depending on the mail server software you use, so that something sent to anything@example.com gets to you.

Comment: But sending something to @example.com would not fall under that subset of anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll post this as an answer, following up from my comment:

> No. However, you can often create a catch-all address, depending on
> the mail server software you use, so that something sent to
> anything@example.com gets to you

As specified in [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-15), a valid email address must have a "locally interpreted string followed by the at-sign character".

As neo pointed out, a space would work, because technically that COULD be interpreted as a valid string by some programs.

But simply @example.com isn't valid, and would never work.

Comment: Obsoleted (again) by [RFC 5322](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322#section-3.4.1).

Comment: Alright, thanks for the answer. The ability to use a space is interesting, but in that case I could just as well use a less confusing character.

Comment: I almost linked to 822, but saw it was obsoleted by 2822. Thanks for pointing that out, Michael. Mental note made.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. A valid email address should have local part and domain part, e.g., local@domain. However, you can use " "@example.org (space between the quotes), but it may not be valid to some server and client. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address) for further information.